# Combining 'use client' and runtime environment variables in next js with app router

Tags: javascript, docker, next.js, docker-compose, environment-variables

As mentioned in the next.js [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#runtime-environment-variables), runtime environment variables can be used on dynamically rendered pages.

The test setup used for the below example is a Next.js 14 project with app router.

Given the below page, the environment variable is indeed replaced by it's runtime value (defined in a docker-compose.yml file):

```js
import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from 'next/cache'
import styles from './page.module.css'

export default function Home() {
  // function called to opt into dynamic rendering
  noStore();
  const value = process.env.SOME_ENV_VARIABLE;

  return (
    <main>
      { value }
    </main>
  )
}
```

However, after adding the `'use client'` directive at the top of the page, the environment variable value defined in the docker-compose file only briefly appears and is then replaced with `undefined`.

(the 'use client' directive is not necessary in this example, but in the project I want to use runtime environment variables, useState is used too)

This is what it looks like repeatedly refreshing the page, it briefly shows 'this-is-a-test-env-value' (the value defined in the docker-compose file) which is then replaced with `undefined`
[image: runtime environment value flashing briefly before being replaced by undefined]

Is there a way to successfully combine the `'use client'` directive and runtime environment variables on a dynamically rendered page?

Comment: I think you need to prefix envs with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` if you want to access them from client code.

Comment: @lagerone That is indeed the case if you want them to be part of the public bundle. If I add the NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix here, then the default set in my .env file is part of the bundle and the value in the runtime environment no longer overrides it.
The issue is that I cannot get it to work with the 'use client' directive, which I need on that page of my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who come looking for an answer to this question, as far as I could find, combining the `'use client'` directive cannot be combined with dynamically rendered pages, and so also not with runtime variables.

I ended up using [server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations) (experimental version in Next.js 13, stable feature in Next.js 14) to serve my need for a server runtime value on the client.